# DOMXPath::evaluate(): Node From Wrong Document

Tags: php, dom

Well here's an interesting one that I can't for the life of me figure out.

I have made some classes that extend PHPs DOMNode classes, and while trying to test them, I'm getting the error in the title, and I don't understand why, as the Node is definitely from the correct Document as I understand it.

My PHPUhit test is as follows:

```
class XPathTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->doc = new Document();
        $this->xpath = new XPath($this->doc);
    }

    /**
     * A single node should be returned from this expression
     */
    public function testEvaluate()
    {
        $xml = '<data><test>node</test></data>';

        $this->doc->loadXML($xml);

        $result = $this->xpath->evaluate('/data/test/text()', $this->doc);

        $this->assertInstanceOf('\\DOMText', $result);
        $this->assertEquals($result->nodeValue, 'node');
    }

}
```

There's nothing really special about my extending classes at this point, they have the default functionality of the parent.

```
DOMXPath::evaluate(): Node From Wrong Document
```

Has anyone come across this error before?

If I don't pass `$this->doc` to the xpath evaluate function, I just get no result at all.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the DOMXPath object must be added to the DOMDocument **after** the DOMDocument has XML loaded into it.

So, the following is the correct way of instantiating this test:

```
class XPathTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->doc = new Document();
        $xml = '<data><test>node</test></data>';
        $this->doc->loadXML($xml);

        $this->xpath = new XPath($this->doc);
    }

    /**
     * A single node should be returned from this expression
     */
    public function testEvaluate()
    {
        $result = $this->xpath->evaluate('//test/text()');

        $this->assertInstanceOf('\\Manneken\\Dom\\Text', $result);
        $this->assertEquals($result->nodeValue, 'node');
    }

}
```

Duh.